# skip-lock-tables and mysqldump

Tags: locking, mysql

Daily we run mysql dumps on about 50 individual databases, package them up and then store them offsite. Some of these databases are rather large and contain myisam tables (which CANNOT be changed so suggesting it is pointless).. I have been reading up on using the skip-lock-tables option when doing a dump but have not read what the downside would be. All I see are basically different iterations of "it could have adverse effects if data is inserted to a table while it is dumping."

What are these adverse effects? Does it just mean we will miss those queries upon a restore or will it mean the dump file will be broken and useless? I honestly could care less if we lose NEW data posted after the dump has started as I am just looking for a snapshot in time.

Can I rely on these database dumps to contain all the data that was saved before issuing the dump.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**--skip-lock-tables** parameter instructs the mysqldump utility not to issue a **LOCK TABLES** command before obtaining the dump which will acquire a READ lock on every table. All tables in the database should be locked, for improved consistency in case of a backup procedure. Even with skip-lock-tables, while a table is dumped, will not receive any INSERTs or UPDATEs whatsoever, as it will be locked due the SELECT required to obtain all records from the table. It looks like this

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM my_large_table
```

and you can see it in the process list with the **SHOW PROCESSLIST** command.
If you are using the MyISAM engine which is non-transactional, locking the tables will not guarantee referential integrity and data consistency in any case, I personally use the **--skip-lock-tables** parameter almost always. In InnoDB use the *--single-transaction* parameter for the expected effect. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've compared a backup of mixed database, with MyISAM and InnoDB tables, with --skip-lock-tables and --single-transaction parameters. The result is the with both options. It looks like they doing exactly the same job. Is it correct ?

Comment: I believe you can use both parameters simultaneously. --single-transaction is mutually exclusive with --lock-tables because locking tables requires committing all pending transactions. Check the [mysqldump manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction).

Comment: You mean you performed 2 MySQL dumps each with one of the options and they resulted to an identical dump?

Comment: Exactly, on the server, where I had no LOCK TABLES permission. And the size of each dump was identical to another one. Didn't used it together.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your point... these options provide the least possible DB operations blocking while performing a logical backup. You sacrifice consistency and you get "availability" by being able to query the database while taking the backup. **Correction:** when using --single-transaction for InnoDB tables you get a perfectly consistent snapshot since everything is performed under a single transaction (which is not surprising - it's the name of the parameter after all!).