# Mysql (myisam) : "waiting for lock" REPLACE blocking all selects

Tags: mysql, myisam

I've a MyISAM table (I can't change it to use InnoDb, do please don't suggest that) which is pretty big (~20GB)
I've a worker which regularly dump this table (I launch is with the --skip-lock-tables option)

During the dump (which takes ~5min), concurrent select can be correctly run, as I would expect. When I go a "REPLACE" during the dump, this REPLACE is "waiting for metadatalock" which seems normal too.

But, every SELECT started after the start the REPLACE will also be "waiting for metadata lock". I can't understand why. Could you help me on this, and tell me how I can have all the selects correctly run (even after this replace)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is:

- Your worker is making a big `SELECT`. The `SELECT` is locking the table with a read lock. By the way, the `skip-lock-tables` only means that you are not locking *all* the tables at once, but the `SELECT` query is still locking each table individually. More info [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415698/skip-lock-tables-and-mysqldump).
- Your `REPLACE` is trying to `INSERT` but has to wait for the first `SELECT` (the dump) to finish in order to acquire a write lock. It is put in the *write lock queue*.
- Every `SELECT` after the `REPLACE` is put in the *read lock queue*.

This is a behavior described in [the doc on table-level locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-table-level-locking):

> Table updates are given higher priority than table retrievals. Therefore, when a lock is released, the lock is made available to the requests in the write lock queue and then to the requests in the read lock queue. This ensures that updates to a table are not “starved” even when there is heavy SELECT activity for the table.

If you want the `SELECT` to not wait for the `REPLACE` you *could* (never actually tested that) try the `LOW_PRIORITY` modifier on your replace.

> If you use the LOW_PRIORITY modifier, execution of the INSERT is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table. This includes other clients that began reading while existing clients are reading, and while the INSERT LOW_PRIORITY statement is waiting. It is possible, therefore, for a client that issues an INSERT LOW_PRIORITY statement to wait for a very long time (or even forever) in a read-heavy environment. (This is in contrast to INSERT DELAYED, which lets the client continue at once.)

However be careful as it might never run if there are always a lot of select.